# STM32 dual CDC (VCP) class

Tags: usb, stm32, cdc

I am using CubeMx in order to generate startup code for the USB virtual com port device. It works fine. But I need to implement 2 virtual com ports on 1 USB interface.

I can't seem to find any source of information how to do it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

I've never done it with two CDC's before, but what you are trying to do is make a 'composite device'.  The following thread has posters who seem to have done it and posted working code, note that it doesn't use CubeMx.

[Multiple USB CDC](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fpublic%2FSTe2ecommunities%2Fmcu%2FLists%2Fcortex_mx_stm32%2FMultiple%20USB%20CDC%20%28USB%20IAD%29%2E%20How&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D7580009C4E14902C3CDE46A77F0FFD06506F5B&currentviews=10037)

A couple of other links in case that doesn't work

[STM32F103 Composite Example](http://codeofphi.com/?p=28)

[STM32 USB Device Library User Manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/99/6b/a7/ec/2a/4b/4b/47/DM00104543.pdf/files/DM00104543.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00104543.pdf)

The device manual is for an F0, but it has examples of composite devices in it. You can likely get example code that matches the manual or code that will run on other STM32's from the ST website.